# How to deploy code on Windows Server 2012

Tags: deployment, windows-server-2012

(I am very new to deploying in a dedicated server.)

I have access to Windows Server 2012 through as Remote Login.

I have to deploy my `html`, `js` files to the server and then access my html page through a URL.

I am not sure where should I keep my files in the server, launch the server and then access my page through a URL.

In my local server in my machine, I kept the files in

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

And I gave access to others to my page through :

```
http://myIPaddress/mypage.html
```

Please suggest where should I keep my code and how can I launch the server.

If anyone can point me to a documentation, even that would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First create web app on the server,
then you can choose any destintion folder for the project.

Follow this documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd394698(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

We need to enable IIS first before deploying our files in Windows Server 2012.

I went through the following document I found in Microsoft website. It was very helpful.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831515.aspx